# sqlalchemy.orm method "validates" breaks query behavior after delete

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here's what looks like a bug with sqlalchmy.orm validates, but maybe I'm just missing something.

I have a table `users` with a column `team_id` which is a foreign key to table `teams`. On my `User` class I'm using the `@validates` decorator on several attrs, including `team_id`.

```
class User(Base, UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    @validates('team_id')
    def validate_team_id(self, key, value):
        assert Team.query.get(value), "invalid 'team_id'"
        return value
```

There is of course a teams table and Team class as well. So far so good.

I can delete a team:

```
foo = Team.query.filter(teamname='foo').first()
db.session.delete(foo)
```

But when I try to commit OR to query anything related to Team:

```
bar = Team.query.filter(teamname='bar').first()
```

This exception occurs: `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` See the partial traceback below.

I put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` inside of `validate_team_id`, so I know that it is only being called on the second query and that `value` is indeed a NoneType, but **why is it being called at all?** Commenting out the `validate_team_id` eliminates this behavior.

Partial traceback:

```
~/miniconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/util.py in set_(state, value, oldvalue, initiator)
    134         def set_(state, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    135             if include_backrefs or not detect_is_backref(state, initiator):
--> 136                 return validator(state.obj(), key, value)
    137             else:
    138                 return value

/home/jeremy/code/my_project/my_app/models.py in validate_team_id(self, key, value)
    411     @validates('team_id')
    412     def validate_team_id(self, key, value):
--> 413         assert Team.query.get(value), "invalid 'team_id'"
    414         return value
    415     

~/miniconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py in get(self, ident)
    921         """
    922         return self._get_impl(
--> 923             ident, loading.load_on_pk_identity)
    924 
    925     def _identity_lookup(self, mapper, primary_key_identity,

~/miniconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py in _get_impl(self, primary_key_identity, db_load_fn, identity_token)
    982         mapper = self._only_full_mapper_zero("get")
    983 
--> 984         if len(primary_key_identity) != len(mapper.primary_key):
    985             raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
    986                 "Incorrect number of values in identifier to formulate "

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: As to why it is being called at all, do you have `relationship`s defined between the two, and if so, what cascade configuration do they have? In other words please provide a [mcve]. It also looks like you're performing what a DB foreign key constraint would do in your application.

Comment: On the DB level, there is a FK constraint: `TABLE "users" CONSTRAINT "users_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams(id)`. There is no cascade configuration between them and on the application level, there is no `sqlalchemy.orm` `relationship` between them.